# why CRC32 is non-linear in gnuradio?

Tags: crc32, gnuradio, telecommunication, usrp, gnuradio-companion

I have a question regarding the non-linearity of the CRC32 in gnuradio.

I am working on a project where i need a linear CRC32 meaning that: crc(a xor b) = crc(a) xor crc(b), where a and b represent a packet.

The implementation of CRC32 in gnuradio is by default non-linear so i had to modify the code to make it linear.

I did some research on the theory behind CRC and i found out 2 reasons behind a non-linear CRC implementation:

1- with a linear CRC, we can have the same CRC for 2 different packets of zeros, for example  crc(0000 0000) = crc(00000 00 00000). So if i add additional zeroes to a packet containing only zeros, well, the CRC will nont be able to detect the errors(additional zeros).

2- the second reason is that with a linear CRC, if i add zeros to the beginning of a packet, the CRC won't be able to detect the errors. for example: crc(10010 1101) = crc(0000 1000 1101)

Now my question is: 
When transmitting packets between two USRPs, bits could have errors(due to bad SNR for example), so a bit "1" could become a bit "0" and vice versa. However, I don't think that bits could be added (like the two cases stated above) to the packets and thus the reasons of implementing a non-linear CRC should not apply to gnuradio.

So why do we have a non-linear CRC in gnuradio by default?

And, if i use a linear CRC when trasmitting between two USRP, would that be a problem?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such CRCs are still linear, just with an added constant. As an analogy, `y = a x` is linear, but so is `y = a x + b`, where `b` is a non-zero constant.

In this case, `crc(a xor b) xor crc(a) xor crc(b)` is a constant for all equal length messages `a` and `b`. That constant is `crc(0)`, i.e. the CRC of all zeros of that same message length.

There is absolutely no problem whatsoever with this sort of linearity, and in fact it has benefits. In particular, a change in the message that adds a prefix of zeros would be detected as an error.